# Jack Audio - Headphone port

Tags: pulseaudio, headphones, ubuntu-studio, jack

I run Ubuntu Studio 19.04 on a HP AMD laptop. I am relatively novice at linux.

I am using Jack audio to run sound for SuperCollider, Ardour, PureData etc.. and I am bridging it to system (puluseaudio sink/source) using 'ubuntu studio control'

I get sound from the speakers but not from headohones even when I restart jack after inserting headpohones. The only way I get sound on headphone port is if I boot with headphones connected.

Is this a Ubuntu Studio/Jack/PulsuAudioBridge bug or could there be a problem on my end?

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu Studio leader here. This is a problem we are aware of in Ubuntu Studio Controls. While there is no official bug report, work is in progress on this issue, fix will hopefully land in Ubuntu Studio 19.10.

The unfortunate part that we have run into is that different hardware manufacturers implement the auto-mute differently, so it is hard to detect. Rest assured, though, we are working on it.

You have already identified one workaround by booting with your headphones plugged-in. There are two more workarounds you can try:

- Plug in your headphones before starting Jack. PulseAudio should do the switching for you. This workaround has had mixed results.
- Open alsamixer in a terminal or open QASMixer and ensure headphone volume is up and unmuted. Basically, this is a way of doing the switch from speakers to headphones manually and is what would be expected automatically.

I hope this helps.

Comment: "Plug in your headphones before starting Jack. PulseAudio should do the switching for you. This workaround has had mixed results."
This definitely works.
I found another work around which is basically a reverse method as I autostart jack at login. Stop jack-make sure pulse audio has switched to headphones from pulse audio sink and then restart jack.
Thank you

Comment: Autojack starting at login is the default, so that's by design; it's the background part of Ubuntu Studio Controls. If you could do me a favor and mark this as answered, that would be great. :)